# How can I get the latest dataset fore each foreign key ID with one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following (simplified) database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wm_renderings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formula_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `svg` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `formula_id` (`formula_id`)
);
```

where `formula_id` is a foreign key.

I want to get the latest rendering for every `formula_id`. But when I write

```
SELECT `id`, `formula_id`, `svg`
FROM `wm_renderings`
GROUP BY `formula_id`
ORDER BY `creation_time` DESC
```

I would get a "random" rendering for each formula_id.

My approach would be to get all formula ids and then send a query for every single formula_id:

```
SELECT `id`, `formula_id`, `svg`
FROM `wm_renderings`
WHERE `formula_id` = 42
ORDER BY `creation_time` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However, that would be a lot of queries.

Can I get the same with only one query?

Comment: FYI: You have no foreign key in there, you just have an index. (Key is an alias for index). Also I would suggest, that you don't use the same name for the column and the index. Use a prefix or something like that.

Comment: I do have a foreign key, but I didn't add it to the simplified schema.

Comment: @fancyPants "Also I would suggest, that you don't use the same name for the column and the index." - Do you mean `KEY `formula_id` (`formula_id`)`? Why do you think that is a bad idea?

Comment: Hm, actually from the top of my head there's nothing that can go wrong. For every `alter` or whatever statement, you have specify `index` or `column` or `table`. It's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the `max`/`latest` per group could be done is various way and one such way is to use `left join`

```
select t1.* from wm_renderings t1
left join wm_renderings t2 on t1.formula_id = t2.formula_id
and t1.creation_time < t2.creation_time
where t2.id is null
```

Here is the documentation on it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Left join and Uncorrelated subs-query are considered to be better in terms of performance.